# How to perform partial template specialization with a parameter pack and non-type template value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, non-type

While trying to [use a compile time std::array in a variadic template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60434033/how-do-i-expand-a-compile-time-stdarray-into-a-parameter-pack), I wrote this partial template specialization:

```cpp
template <typename array_wrapper> struct Test1;
template <std::size_t... A> struct Test1<any_type<std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(A)>{A...}>> {}; //(2)
```

which leads to a compilation error `<Expression> has incomplete type and cannot be defined` for my attempts to partial template specialization for `Test1` and `Test2` when I am trying to use it; hence -- as I understand it -- the usage (3) does not match the definition (2):

```
int main() {
  Test1<any_type<std::array<std::size_t, 2>{1, 2}>> a; // (3)
}
```

I don't understand why this is the case though. When experimenting with the example, I realize that this happens when I am 'hiding' the content of the parameter pack in my `any_type` struct:

```cpp
#include <array>

template <auto f> struct any_type;

template <typename array_wrapper> struct Test1;
template <std::size_t... A> struct Test1<any_type<std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(A)>{A...}>> {};

template <typename array_wrapper> struct Test2;
template <int... A> struct Test2<any_type<std::get<0>(A...)>> {};

template <typename array_wrapper> struct Test3;
template <int A> struct Test3<any_type<A>> {};

int main() {
  //Test1<any_type<std::array<std::size_t, 2>{1, 2}>> a;
  //Test2<any_type<1>> b;
  Test3<any_type<1>> ok;
}
```

Test1 and Test2 fail with the same error, and Test3 works fine. Why does the partial template specialization 'fail' in the frist two cases? As I understand it, the declaration provides the 'interface' in order to use the struct, and the arguments in the specialization are matched to teh arguments which are actually provided.

**Code**
The code can be found [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x9YuYPL3Y2QeWXEE).

**Compile options:**
I use`g++-10.0 (GCC) 10.0.1 20200124 (experimental)` and compile via `g++ -std=c++2a file.cc`, c++2a is required because I use non-type template parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a finite set of patterns that template arguments can be deduced from. For template non-type arguments, that set is just (from [[temp.deduct.type]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#8)):

- `type[i]`
- `template-name<i>`  (where template-name refers to a class template)
- `TT<i>`

... and that's it. Your `Test3` matches the 2nd form, and the other two don't match at all.

It's not clear how the `Test2` example would work at all. The `Test1` example may be something we want to consider as the use of non-type template parameters proliferates after C++20, but it's just not something that's currently valid.